# Set button style programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I'm programmatically creating new buttons and adding them to a LinearLayout, however I want to initialize these buttons with a predefined style. I've spent some time searching for a solution and trying out answers, but I still can't seem to get it to work.

When I add a new button to the layout, it should look like the buttons (near the top) in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxDXB.png).

I've tried creating an xml file in res/values/ and initializing a button with `new Button(context, null, R.style.ChoiceButton)`, but it doesn't work resulting in [this happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCaXP.png).

I've also tried the workaround of creating a new layout xml for the button and using `(Button)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.choice_buttton_layout, null)`, but that also didn't work, [resulting in this (two buttons to show lack of margin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUuSn.png).

**res/values/choice_button.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="ChoiceButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">7dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">250dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ff27ae60</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
        <item name="android:enabled">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Snippet from Main.java**

```
public void btnAdd_click(View view) {
        Button newBtn = new Button(getApplicationContext(), null, R.style.ChoiceButton);
        newBtn.setText("new button");
        newBtn.setId(Util.generateViewId());

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutTop);
        layout.addView(newBtn);
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

[A bit long to paste in here.](http://pastie.org/private/hkcsuec7gibwhfrbwm9c3q)

Is there just something I'm missing? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok @kin3tik, I found an old application I made with some custom button.. see what it looks like :

[image]

there is my xml for one button :

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/num1"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/num1"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I created file .xml in my drawable folder custombutton.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@color/bleuperso"/> // you can put #XXXXXX for the color you want 
<corners android:radius="4dp"/>
```

And I just put the style in java :

```
Bfrancois.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custombutton);
```

With this you should be able to find yourself ;)